# How do I revert Extension Development option for Javascript in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-extensions

Accidentally enabled Extension Development with Javascript in VS Code, and now whenever I try to compile JS code and run it regularly in the console, it automatically opens an Extension Development Host window, as if I'm trying to develop an extension for VS Code. Searched everywhere but couldn't understand how to change this. How do I revert this?

Looked in Extension settings for Javascript, the command palette, VS Code documentation and Stack overflow but couldn't find the instructions on how to disable this.

Comment: change the launch config in the Run/Debug bar